# Data Preparation - Python

Tags: python

I have a first dataframe containing a serie called 'Date', and a variable number n of series called 'People_1' to 'People_n' :

```
Id              Date                    People_1         People_2    People_3           People_4    People_5        People_6     People_7
12.0    Sat Dec 19 00:00:00 EST 1970    Loretta Lynn    Owen Bradley          
13.0    Sat Jun 07 00:00:00 EDT 1980    Sissy Spacek    Loretta Lynn Owen Bradley   
14.0    Sat Dec 04 00:00:00 EST 2010    Loretta Lynn    Sheryl Crow Miranda Lambert 
15.0    Sat Aug 09 00:00:00 EDT 1969    Charley Pride   Dallas Frazier  A.L. "Doodle"   Chet Atkins Jack Clement    Bob Ferguson    Felton Jarvis
```

I also have another dataframe containing a list of names and biographic datas :

```
  People          Birth_date                Birth_state      Sex    Ethnicity
Charles Kelley  Fri Sep 11 00:00:00 EDT 1981    GA           Male   Caucasian
Hillary Scott   Tue Apr 01 00:00:00 EST 1986    TN          Female  Caucasian
Reba McEntire   Mon Mar 28 00:00:00 EST 1955    OK          Female  Caucasian
Wanda Jackson   Wed Oct 20 00:00:00 EST 1937    OK          Female  Caucasian
Carrie UnderwoodThu Mar 10 00:00:00 EST 1983    OK          Female  Caucasian
Toby Keith      Sat Jul 08 00:00:00 EDT 1961    OK          Male    Caucasian
David Bellamy   Sat Sep 16 00:00:00 EDT 1950    FL          Male    Caucasian
Howard Bellamy  Sat Feb 02 00:00:00 EST 1946    FL          Male    Caucasian
Keith Urban Thu Oct 26 00:00:00 EDT 1967    Northland       Male    Caucasian
Miranda Lambert Thu Nov 10 00:00:00 EST 1983    TX          Female  Caucasian
Sam Hunt        Sat Dec 08 00:00:00 EST 1984    GA          Male    Caucasian
Johnny Cash     Fri Feb 26 00:00:00 EST 1932    AR          Male    Caucasian
June Carter     Sun Jun 23 00:00:00 EDT 1929    VA          Female  Caucasian
Merle Haggard   Tue Apr 06 00:00:00 EST 1937    CA          Male    Caucasian
Waylon Jennings Tue Jun 15 00:00:00 EDT 1937    TX          Male    Caucasian
Willie Nelson   Sat Apr 29 00:00:00 EST 1933    TX          Male    Caucasian
Loretta Lynn    Thu Apr 14 00:00:00 EST 1932    KY          Female  Caucasian
Sissy Spacek    Sun Dec 25 00:00:00 EST 1949    TX          Female  Caucasian
Sheryl Crow Sun Feb 11 00:00:00 EST 1962        MO          Female  Caucasian
Charley Pride   Sun Mar 18 00:00:00 EST 1934    MS          Male    African American
Rodney Clawon   ?                               TX          Male    Caucasian
Nathan Chapman  ?                               TN          Male    Caucasian
```

I want to get for each date the biographic datas of each people involved that day :

```
    Date                        Birth_state      Sex    Ethnicity
 Sat Dec 19 00:00:00 EST 1970   KY              Female  Caucasian
 Sat Jun 07 00:00:00 EDT 1980   TX              Female  Caucasian
 Sat Jun 07 00:00:00 EDT 1980   KY              Female  Caucasian
 Sat Dec 04 00:00:00 EST 2010   KY              Female  Caucasian
 Sat Dec 04 00:00:00 EST 2010   MO              Female  Caucasian
 Sat Dec 04 00:00:00 EST 2010   TX              Female  Caucasian
 Sat Aug 09 00:00:00 EDT 1969   MS              Male    African American
```

Precision : 
Consider that my bio datas aren't complete yet, some names are missing, which explains why I don't have a row for each person.

So is there a way to perform this task in Python ?
Lionel

Answer (score 1):

You may to use left join in pandas to join the two tables first and then select the columns you need.

For example, you can first aggregate all person into a new column, for example, named 'person'. Then add one single row for each person. After you finished doing this, then left join two dataframe as you did.

Comment: Hi. thanks for your feedback. When I execute : df3 = df1.join(df2,how = 'left'), I don't obtain the expected result. Can you describe your solution ?